# Row evaluation in a file

Tags: text-processing

I have a source file like this:

```
server1 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated
server2 Vulnerable Vulnerable Mitigated
server3 Mitigated Vulnerable Vulnerable
server4 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated
server5 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated
server6 Vulnerable Vulnerable Vulnerable
```

I want to compare 2nd and 4th element of each row and add in a 5th element following this logic:

If either one ( 2nd or 4th element ) says vulnerable - 5th element will be Vulnerable ( and I want it printed in the same row  like this:

```
server2 Vulnerable Vulnerable Mitigated Vulnerable
```

If only both ( 2nd and 4th ) are mitigated - Then 5th element will be mitigated

You can ignore the 3rd element.

Comment: server1 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated server2 Vulnerable Vulnerable Mitigated server3 Mitigated Vulnerable Vulnerable server4 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated server5 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated server6 Vulnerable Vulnerable Vulnerable

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$2 == "Vulnerable" || $4 == "Vulnerable" { $5 = "Vulnerable" } { print }' file
```

Result when using it on the example data:

```
server1 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated
server2 Vulnerable Vulnerable Mitigated Vulnerable
server3 Mitigated Vulnerable Vulnerable Vulnerable
server4 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated
server5 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated
server6 Vulnerable Vulnerable Vulnerable Vulnerable
```

The `awk` code looks at the second and fourth fields, and if any of these is exactly the string `Vulnerable` a fifth field is introduced. All fields (of all input lines) are then printed.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

For both conditions:

> - If either one ( 2nd or 4th element ) says `vulnerable` - 5th element will be `Vulnerable`
> - If only both ( 2nd and 4th ) are `mitigated` - Then 5th element will be `Mitigated`

---

```
awk '$2$4 ~ /[vV]ulnerable/{ $5="Vulnerable" }
     $2 ~ /[mM]itigated/ && $2 == $4{ $5="Mitigated" }1' file
```

The output:

```
server1 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated Mitigated
server2 Vulnerable Vulnerable Mitigated Vulnerable
server3 Mitigated Vulnerable Vulnerable Vulnerable
server4 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated Mitigated
server5 Mitigated Vulnerable Mitigated Mitigated
server6 Vulnerable Vulnerable Vulnerable Vulnerable
```

Comment: The 2nd response covers my entire scenario. Thanks for the 1st response - Yes it does cover the Vulnerable scenario like you had stated. I've used the 2nd awk response.  I am still sorting out the output and will post anything else that comes up  - But thank you so much guys for your prompt responses. - Param